# What does this expression mean in Russian? "во даёт!"

Tags: грамматика, узус

Give me some phrases examples as well plz

Comment: Hi Laurel, this works another way around - you encounter a phrase in some context, provide the phrase and context, explain what you think it means and why you still have doubts and ask this question.

Comment: https://ochenporusski.com/russian-dictionary/vo-dayot/

Comment: It is usually means surprise or admiration. It is similarly to "I'm surprised".

Comment: Actually don't understand why this question was closed because I think it doesn't require a context. "во даёт!” can be used when you are surprised with somebody's actions, when he is exceeding your expectations. Example: "Во даёт! Он прыгает уже 2 часа без перерыва!"

Comment: @Kosh this question is easily answered by a dictionary. It's when a dictionary falls short that we people try to help with an answer.